# ionic2 how to select only one check box and get the selected check box value

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have one screen, where i have around 20 question and answers which will come from db. so i use check box for show options. i was not able to find the solution till now.

What i need is, i need to check only one check box out of 4 check box per questions. and need to get the value of selected check box.here is my code :

in my **.js** what should i need to do to get the checked value , and only one selection of check box among 4 option of check box.

thanks in advance !!

Full html code:

```
 <ion-header >
     <ion-navbar color="navcolr" no-border-bottom>
     <ion-buttons>
     <button (click)="canceltap()" style="font-size: 15px;text-transform: none;" ion-button>Cancel
        </button>
        </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title >Mock Test</ion-title>

      <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button type="submit" (click)="finished()" block>
            <ion-icon style="font-size: 15px;">Submit</ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-buttons>
     </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

     <ion-content fullscreen>

        <ion-card *ngFor="let card of subdata">

          <ion-item>
    <div class="item-text-wrap" style="text-align: center;font-weight: 400;font-size: 15px;">

      <label>Questions: </label><label class="item-text-wrap" style="color: #303030;">{{card.Question}}</label>
    </div>


    <div style="height: 1px;background-color: #696969;margin-left: 4%;margin-right: 4%;margin-top: 3%;"></div>
    <div style="margin-top: 3%;">
      <img src="http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/example.png">
    </div>


          </ion-item>
           <ion-card-content>

           <div style="margin-left: 4%;margin-top: 6%;">
    <ol id="options" type="A" >
       <div style="width: 10px;"></div>
          <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <label>
              <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer1}}" required>
            {{card.Answer1}}
            </label>
          </li>
          <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <label>
              <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer2}}">
           {{card.Answer2}}
            </label>
          </li>
          <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <label>
              <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer3}}">
              {{card.Answer3}}
            </label>
          </li>
          <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
            <label>
              <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer4}}" >
          {{card.Answer4}}
            </label>
          </li>
        </ol>


     </div>

    <button ion-button full round id="Ansbtn" (click)="onButtonClick()" [disabled]="!isenabled">View Answer/Description</button>


     <div class="item-text-wrap" *ngIf="buttonClicked" style="text-align: center;font-weight: 400;font-size: 15px;">
     <div style="height: 1px;background-color: #696969;margin-left: 4%;margin-right: 4%;margin-top: 3%;"></div>

    <label  style="color: #303030;">Answer: {{card.CorrectAnswer}}</label><br>
    <label class="item-text-wrap" style="color: #303030;">Explanations: {{card.AnsDescription}}</label>
    <div style="height: 1px;background-color: #696969;margin-left: 4%;margin-right: 4%;margin-top: 3%;"></div>
    </div>

          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>

    <div style="height: 10px;background-color: #ededed;"> 

    </div>
    <div style="height: 30px;text-align: center;" *ngIf="buttonClicked"> 
      <label  style="color: red;font-size: 18px;">SCORE: 1</label><br>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 30px;background-color: #ededed;"> 

    </div>



</ion-content>
```

Comment: If users need to select only one out of a few options use radio buttons. Give them the same name and make them required.

Comment: @Berend de Groot i tried with radio button, but i have 10 question in same page as scroll. so if user select first option for my first option is selecting. then if user select any option for second question, the first question selected answer is automatically uncheck

Answer (score 0):

I would change all the checkboxes to radio input, give them all the same name and add an actually value to them. I also added the "required" attribute to your first input so they should select at least one of the radio buttons.

Lets say this is question one:

```
<ol id="options" type="A" >
   <div style="width: 10px;"></div>
      <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <label>
          <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer1}}" required>
        {{card.Answer1}}
        </label>
      </li>
      <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <label>
          <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer2}}">
       {{card.Answer2}}
        </label>
      </li>
      <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <label>
          <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer3}}">
          {{card.Answer3}}
        </label>
      </li>
      <li style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <label>
          <input name="question1" type="radio" value="{{card.Answer4}}" >
      {{card.Answer4}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
```

Now because all these 4 input fields have the same name and because it is a radio button only one of them can be selected. Now the second question would be the same as above only a different name.

Comment: should i need to do any extra code in my `.js` file

Comment: No, this should be enough.

Comment: i tried ur solution. but when i select first question answer and if i scroll down and select my second question answer , my first question selected answer is again uncheck automatically

Comment: Did you change the names of all the other input fields? If the names of the input fields are the same as the one I posted above then yes it will be unchecked. Maybe post your entire html so I can take a look at it?

Comment: i have updated. actually i dont know how can i change the value of each option. also i need to print the selected answer radiobutton or/ selected checkbox value at last ..

Comment: I don't understand anymore, I see only one question in your html. Where is the rest?

Comment: i am calling the question from my database api. and i am binding the question and options there

Comment: here my `<ion-card *ngFor="let card of subdata"> ` my question and answer will be under this `subdata`

Comment: can you help me for this problem :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244660/menu-is-not-working-when-i-push-the-screen-ionic-3